# Kyverno ClusterPolicy exception not working as expected while verifying ocisourcelabels

Tags: kubernetes, policies

Created the below cluster policy which blocks all images which does not have `com.*****.os-policy.verified` in their docker label and this is working as expected.

```
apiVersion: kyverno.io/v2beta1
kind: ClusterPolicy
metadata:
  name: disallow-host-namespaces
spec:
  validationFailureAction: Enforce
  background: false
  rules:
    - name: verify-oci-annotation
      match:
        any:
          - resources:
              kinds:
                - Pod
      validate:
        message: "Images must specify a source/base image from which they are built."
        foreach:
          - list: "request.object.spec.containers"
            context:
              - name: imageData
                imageRegistry:
                  reference: "{{ element.image }}"
              - name: ocisourcelabels
                variable:
                  jmesPath: imageData.configData.config.Labels | keys(@)
                  default: []
            deny:
              conditions:
                all:
                  - key: "com.*****.os-policy.verified"
                    operator: AnyNotIn
                    value: "{{ ocisourcelabels}}"
```

But when I tried to create a `PolicyException` to skip the policy for deployments with specific annotations its not working.

```
apiVersion: kyverno.io/v2alpha1
kind: PolicyException
metadata:
  name: delta-exception
  namespace: test
spec:
  exceptions:
    - policyName: disallow-host-namespaces
      ruleNames:
        - verify-oci-annotation
        - autogen-host-namespaces
  match:
    any:
      - resources:
          kinds:
            - Pod
            - Deployment
          namespaces:
            - test
```

The below deployment I tried after applied the `Policyexcemption` but it will fail

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    *****.com-os-policy-internal-use: "true"
    *****.com-os-policy-break-glass: "true"

spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  replicas: 2 # tells deployment to run 2 pods matching the template
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: nginx
          image: junkimagename:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
```

But with the same `Policyexcemption` if I tried to create a pod it will work

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: badpod
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    *****.com/os-policy.internal-use: "true"
    *****.com/os-policy.break-glass: "true"
spec:
  automountServiceAccountToken: false
  containers:
    - image: junkimagename:latest
      name: node-exporter
```

How to write a `PolicyException` here in this scenario which can allow the `kind:Deployment` to work if specifc annotations are provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could fix this with a `preconditions`. This helped in removing the need to add an `excemptionpolicy`

In precondtion I am checking if there is an annotation defined for the image then skip this policy.

`Example`:

```
apiVersion: kyverno.io/v1
kind: Policy
metadata:
  name: kyverno-policy
  namespace: test
spec:
  validationFailureAction: Enforce
  background: true
  rules:
    - name: verify-oci-annotation
      match:
        any:
          - resources:
              kinds:
                - Pod
      preconditions:
        all:
          - key: "{{ request.\"object\".metadata.annotations.\"*****.com/os-policy.internal-use\" || '' }}"
            operator: NotEquals
            value: "true"
      validate:
        message: "Images must specify a source/base image from which they are built."
        foreach:
          - list: "request.object.spec.containers"
            context:
              - name: imageData
                imageRegistry:
                  reference: "{{ element.image }}"
              - name: ocisourcelabels
                variable:
                  jmesPath: imageData.configData.config.Labels | keys(@)
                  default: []
            deny:
              conditions:
                all:
                  - key: "com.******.os-policy.verified"
                    operator: AnyNotIn
                    value: "{{ ocisourcelabels}}"
```